# Using KDE Wallet in fluxbox /openbox or other "light" window managers

Tags: openbox, fluxbox, kwallet

I have stored chromium passwords in kwalled5, from KDE.
I'd like to continue using wallet in fluxbox.

I tried while in `fluxbox` to start `kwalletd5` then run `chromium` – the same way as it was started in KDE, but that's not enough as passwords are not loaded.

```
kwalletd5 &
chromium --password-store=detect &
```

Any idea what next needs to be started in order to use kwallet from fluxbox / openbox?